# is there a way to install 'python-setuptools' without installing all the requirements?

Tags: software-installation

**https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/python-setuptools_44.0.0-2_all.deb.html**
there so many packages on the link above,that i have to install for installing 'python-setuptools'.Is there a way to install 'python setuptools' with installing all other requirements mentioned in the download page.I am using ubuntu 20.04 should i check that all the others are in my system already?Thanks,I am new to linux.

Comment: If you install it using apt, all dependencies will be checked and install automatically.

Comment: I see only two required packages: `python-pkg-resources`, and python itself.

Comment: thanks i did sudo apt install python-setuptools,i hope the dependencies will be checked and installed automatically,I installed setuptools by apt because it is a buildtime dependency to numba ,if I 'conda install numba ' and 'conda update numba ' will numba's buildtime,runtime and optional buildtime and optional runtime dependecies will be installed ? @Pilot6

Comment: @Jos you need to click on those and scroll to middle you will see more 'Requires' headings,I was trying to install requirements to requirements to reqirements.. :-0

Answer (score 2):

Run

```
sudo apt install python-setuptools
```

and all will be installed as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the normal `apt` install (edit: as pilot6 has added) an alternativ way to install python-setuptools is through wget

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python
```

as explained on their [installation page](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/3.3/#unix-wget)

Comment: Thanks,for mentioning.